# Find users not in an organization

Tags: sql, join

Given this data:

```
users
  id    name
  ==    ====
  1     Alice
  2     Bob
  3     Carl

organizations
  id    name
  ==    ====
  1     Aaa
  2     Bbb

memberships
  id    organization_id   user_id
  ==    ===============   =======
  1     1                 1
  2     2                 1
  3     1                 2
```

I want to find users that do not belong to a particular organization X:

- users with no membership records at all

  AND
- users with membership records, but not for organization X.

For example, I want users that are not in organization 2.  I am expecting:

```
users.id
========
2
3
```

Attempting with this join isn't working:

```
SELECT *
FROM users left join memberships on memberships.user_id = users.id
where memberships.id is null or memberships.organization_id <> 1
```

It's returning users 1,2,3 since 1 matches on the second where condition.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting your JOIN to organization of 2 and then testing for null is the one way to do what you're looking for e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN memberships 
         ON memberships.user_id = users.id 
            AND memberships.organization_id = 2 
WHERE  memberships.id IS NULL
```

You can also use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id from memberships where organization_id = 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks, took a while to grok it but I see now!

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*
from users u
left join memberships m
on u.id = m.user_id
left join organizations o
on m.organization_id = o.id
where m.organization_id not in (2)
```

EDIT: modified to include all users

Comment: This doesn't seem to include users that have no memberships at all.

Comment: @jemminger try out the modified query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the minus set operator:

select "name" from users
minus
select "name" from users u inner join memberships m on u.id = m.user_id inner join organizations o on m.organization_id = o.id and o."name" = 'X'

Answer (score 0):

```
select Users.*
from users 
inner join memberships 
on Users.id = memberships.id
left join organizations 
on memberships.organization_id = organizations.id 
where memberships.id is null  AND memberships.organization_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using the exists clause:

```
 select * from users
 where not exists 
    (select memberships.id from memberships 
      inner join organizations on memberships.organization_id = organizations.id 
      and memberships.user_id = users.id
      where organizations.id = 2)
```